# how does one combine conditionals into one "when" statement?

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.10.x

I looked at [How to define multiple when conditions in Ansible](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-define-multiple-when-conditions-in-ansible/), and similar posts.

I'm trying to test if 2 different substring are in a variable. I've tried

```yaml
default/main.yml
----------------
# Default path can be overridden in task
repo_url: "https://someUrl/development"

tasks/main.yml
--------------
- debug:
    msg: "URL={{ repo_url }}"
- name: Override default path
  set_fact:
    repo_url: "https://someUrl/releases"
  when: ('"development" not in web_version') and 
        ('"feature" not in web_version')
- debug:
    msg: "URL={{ repo_url }}"
```

I use above task like this for example

```
$ ansible-playbook ... -e web_version=development_ myTask.yml
```

But I get

```yaml
TASK [exa-web : debug] *************************************************
ok: [10.227.x.x] => {
    "msg": "URL=https://someUrl/development"
}
TASK [exa-web : Override default path] *************************************************
ok: [10.227.x.x]

TASK [exa-web : debug] *************************************************
ok: [10.227.x.x] => {
    "msg": "URL=https://someUrl/releases"
}
```

I don't expect the `set_fact` task to run, but it does; hence it overrides the default `repo_url`. So apparently I'm setting my `when` condition wrong.

I've also tried this to no avail.

```yaml
- name: Override default path
  set_fact:
    repo_url: "https://someUrl/releases"
  when: '"development_" not in web_version and 
         "feature_" not in web_version'
```

Essentially, I need the task to run if I execute my playbook like this

```
$ ansible-playbook ... -e web_version=1.4.44 myTask.yml
```

What's the correct syntax? TIA

**UPDATE**

Seems like `when` doesn't like `()`? I just simplified the condition for now, and this works

```yaml
- name: Override default path
  set_fact:
    repo_url: "https://someUrl/releases"
  when: '"development" not in web_version'
```

but not this?

```yaml
- name: Override default path
  set_fact:
    repo_url: "https://someUrl/releases"
  when: ('"development" not in web_version')
```

**Really???**

Comment: I've addressed your latest update in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt...

```yaml
- name: Override default path
  set_fact:
    repo_url: "https://someUrl/releases"
  when: '"development_" not in web_version and 
         "feature_" not in web_version'
```

...seems syntactically correct. In a playbook like this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    repo_url: "https://someUrl/development"
  tasks:
  - name: Override default path
    set_fact:
      repo_url: "https://someUrl/releases"
    when: '"development_" not in web_version and 
           "feature_" not in web_version'

  - debug:
      msg: "URL={{ repo_url }}"
```

If we run it like this:

```
ansible-playbook -e web_version=development_ playbook.yaml
```

We see as output:

```yaml
TASK [Override default path] ****************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "URL=https://someUrl/development"
}
```

And if we run it like this:

```
ansible-playbook -e web_version=1.4.44 playbook.yaml
```

We see:

```yaml
TASK [Override default path] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "URL=https://someUrl/releases"
}
```

That seems to do exactly what you want. Note that you're looking for the string `development_` (with a trailing underscore) in your `when` statement, rather than `development` as in the first example, but that's an easy fix.

---

While your code works just fine, I find it helpful to use one of YAML's quote operators for writing multi-line `when` statements, since it avoids me getting confused by nested quotes in the expression:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    repo_url: "https://someUrl/development"
  tasks:
  - name: Override default path
    set_fact:
      repo_url: "https://someUrl/releases"
    when: >-
      "development_" not in web_version and
      "feature_" not in web_version

  - debug:
      msg: "URL={{ repo_url }}"
```

---

Re: your update, this doesn't work...

```yaml
- name: Override default path
  set_fact:
    repo_url: "https://someUrl/releases"
  when: ('"development" not in web_version')
```

...because of bad quoting. You are effectively writing:

```yaml
when: ("a string")
```

And a non-empty string evaluates as `true` in a boolean expression. Always put the quotes at the *beginning* of the expression. E.g., this works just fine:

```yaml
when: >-
  ("development" not in web_version)
```

As does the syntactically identical:

```yaml
when: '("development" not in web_version)'
```

Comment: Thanks you. I corrected my example, my playbook invocation has `-e web_version=development_`. I'll  try you simple playbook.